# CCMenu::menuWithItems() deprecated

Tags: deprecated

I made a CCMenu object and want to add an item to it but the menuWithItem() method appears deprecated and thus the item doesn't get added to my menu. Here is how am using it:

```
    CCMenuItemFont* pExitButton = CCMenuItemFont::itemWithString(
                                                             "Exit",
                                                             this,
                                                          SEL_MenuHandler(CallbackOnExit));

    CCMenu* pMenu = (CCMenu::menuWithItem(pExitButton, NULL);
```

what is the other possible way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CCMenuItemFont* pExitButton = CCMenuItemFont::**itemFromString**(
                                                             "Exit",
                                                             this,
                                                          SEL_MenuHandler(CallbackOnExit));